# Solve for $ A $ from $ A {A}^{T} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I'm sure that I knew how to do this once many moons ago and that it's really simple.

I have a matrix $ X $ which is defined as: 
$$
X = A {A}^{T} 
$$

How do I find $ A $ given $ X $?

Comment: What is $X$? Perhaps saying what $X$ is would simplify the problem. Also, I believe you mean months, not moons.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar "moons" is a more poetic way to put it.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Didn't think of it that way. Thanks for clearing that! :-)

Comment: Does $X$ satisfy $X=X^T$? If not, then $X$ cannot be written as $AA^T$ for a matrix $A$.

Comment: I think that the following link about Cholesky decomposition could be useful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: Also, typically, this equation, where $X$ is given and $A$ is unknown, has infinitely many solutions. For instance, suppose that $X$ is the identity matrix. Then all you can say is that $A$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a valid choice of $A$, but that choice is certainly not unique.

In particular, as long as $A$ is real, the matrix $X = AA^T$ is positive semi-definite.  As such, there is a unique positive semi-definite matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = X$.  Since $B$ is positive semidefinite, we also have $B = B^T$, so that
$$
BB^T = B^2 = X
$$
There are, however, more interesting ways to break up $A$ in such a manner.  A particularly useful instance of this is the so-called [Cholesky-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

To answer in the most general possible way: if $AA^T = X$, then we can take the matrix $B = AU$, where $U$ is any orthogonal matrix, and find that $BB^T = X$.

In fact, if $X$ doesn't have full rank, we can have $A$ be a $n \times m$ matrix, with $m$ greater than or equal to the rank of $X$.