# Least squares solution to $A^TA ≃ X$ for non-square $A$ given $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am sure that there is a fairly simple solution based on the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse or singular value decomposition, but I cannot seem to make any headway in this problem with these methods. My problem is as follows:

How does one determine the least-squares solution for an unknown non-square matrix $A$ given

$$A^TA ≃ X$$

for a known $X∈ℝ^{n×n}$ and knowing that $A∈ℝ^{m×n}$ where $m≠n$.

The same question has been asked and answered for square A, but I need to know an approximate solution for non-square A.

[Solve for A from A x transpose(A)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832384/solve-for-a-from-a-x-transposea)

Hand-holding solutions and/or examples are greatly appreciated, but any references or relevant theorems/keywords are welcome as well. Please let me know if I need to elaborate or make my question more precise.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit:
Following the comment by User7530 below, what I mean by least-squares solution is this:
$$min_{A^{m×n}}∥A^TA−X∥^2_F$$

where $∥M∥_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: What do you mean by "least-squares solution"? You are trying to solve
$$\min_{A_{m\times n}} \|A^TA-X\|^2_F$$
where $\|M\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Adding this to the question. Thanks for the response!

Comment: What keeps you from just zero padding the square solution when m>n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $  there is theorem called the [Eckart Young Mirsky Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation). It states the following

$$A = U \Sigma V^{T}  $$

with $ U, V^{T} $ being orthogonal matrices and $ \Sigma $ is a diagonal matrices such with singular values. The following is true.

$$A_{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_{i}u_{i} v_{i}^{t} $$
$$\| A - A_{k} \|_{2} = \| \sum_{i=k+1}^{k} \sigma_{i}u_{i} v_{i}^{t} \| = \sigma_{k+1}$$

Now

$$ \| A^{T}A - X \|_{2}   $$

The nearest matrix is rank k approximation under this norm as above then

$$ \| (U\Sigma V^{T})^{T}(U \Sigma V^{T}) - (U_{k}\Sigma_{k}V_{k}^{T})^{T} (U_{k}\Sigma_{k}V_{k}^{T})  \|_{2}  $$
$$ \| V\Sigma U U \Sigma V^{T} - V_{k}\Sigma_{k}^{T}U_{k}U_{k}\Sigma_{k}V_{k}^{T}  \|_{2}  $$

$$ \| V \Sigma^{2} V^{T} - V_{k}\Sigma_{k}^{2}V_{k}^{T}  \|_{2}  $$

where

$$V_{k} \Sigma_{k}^{2}V_{k}^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_{i}^{2} v_{i}v_{i}^{t}  $$

Now the expression above showed

$$\| A - A_{k} \|_{2} = \| \sum_{i=k+1}^{k} \sigma_{i}u_{i} v_{i}^{t} \| = \sigma_{k+1}$$

$$ \| A^{T}A  -X \| =\| \sum_{i=k+1}^{k} \sigma_{i}^{2} v_{i}v_{i}^{t} \| = \sigma_{k+1}^{2}$$

I believe. This is more or less saying that the solution to the least squares problem is building it iteratively from some eigenspace. That is typically how it works. It doesn't explicitly build the normal equations.

More specifically

$$V\Sigma^{2} V^{T} = V \Lambda V^{T}  $$
$$ \| A^{T}A  -X \| =\| \sum_{i=k+1}^{k} \lambda_{i} v_{i}v_{i}^{t} \| = \lambda_{k+1} $$

If you follow this as I decomposed the matrix $X$ with $A^{T}A$. All $A^{T}A$ is the nearest matrix made of the eigendecomposition from $X$ Each matrix $A$ is built from a singular value decomposition. The way the SVD works if you read about it is the following.

$$ A^{T}A = (U \Sigma V)^{T} (U \Sigma V^{T}) $$
$$ A^{T}A = ((V^{T})^{T} \Sigma^{T}  U^{T} U \Sigma  V^{T} $$
by the properties of transposes and unitary matrices
$$ A^{T}A = V \Sigma^{T} \Sigma V^{T}  $$
$$ A^{T}A = V \Sigma^{2} V^{T} $$
$$ A^{T}A = V \Lambda V^{T} $$

Meaning the matrix $A$ is $U\Sigma V^{T}$ however the nearest matrix under the 2 norm is a rank k approximation so we truncate it.

So let's say. Technically this matrix can be measured against the matrix X I think.

$$ A = U_{k}\Sigma_{k} V_{k}^{T} $$

Comment: I don't understand this answer.

Comment: one moment editting

Comment: So what I am hearing is $∥VΣ^2V^T−U_kΣ_kV^T_k∥_2$ is the minimum possible value of the norm, where $X$ is decomposed in line with the Eckart Young Mirsky Theorem such that $X=U_kΣ_kV^T_k$, and $A=VΣ^2V^T$. Is that correct?

Comment: I didn't edit one part above there.  I'm trying to figure out how to express that. It would be better to write it as an eigendecomp I think.  There is a line where it is still an svd

Comment: Geronimo, thanks for the answer. I think I get it after a bit more digging. I do think you missed a few transposes in the lines after "The nearest matrix is rank k approximation...", so if you wanted to edit for the next person to find this that might be helpful. Also, your final answer gives an n by n matrix not an m by n matrix, but I think I get the idea enough to figure that out myself. Plus 1 for helpfulness (although I need more reputation for it to count), and once I get it I will credit you with the solution.

Comment: I will attempt to edit this again. However i lost my glasses when i woke up :(. So may be a few

Comment: some edits for what the matrix A is now.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer Geronimo, very helpful. I will post the full solution above in a little while