# test of solving XTX=A for X !!

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratics, symmetric-matrices, elliptic-equations

according to answerd questions:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2858336/305862
and
[How to find a matrix that produced a symmetric matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550167/how-to-find-a-matrix-that-produced-a-symmetric-matrix)

to find a matrix **X** which produces a given symmetric matrix **A** at equation:

$$ X^{T} X = A $$

we can decompose **A** as:

$$ A = O DO^{T} = O \sqrt{D} \sqrt{D} O^{T} = (\sqrt{D} {O}^T)^{T} \sqrt{D} O^{T} $$

so :
$$ X = \sqrt{D} {O}^T $$
is the answer where **D** is diagonal eigen value matrix and **O** is the orthogonal eigen vector.

for proof I made a supposed matrix as follow:

$$
X=\begin{bmatrix} 1.2 & -0.1 & 0.2\\ 0.2 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\ -0.1 & -0.3 & 1.1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

so the A matrix will be :

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1.49 & 0.09 & 0.15 \\ 0.09 & 0.91 & -0.26 \\ 0.15 & -0.26 & 1.26 \end{bmatrix}
$$

accordingly the **D** and **O** matrices are as follow:

$$
D=\begin{bmatrix} 1.56657 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.741073 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1.35236 \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
O=\begin{bmatrix} -0.869483 & 0.199387 & -0.451934 \\ 0.0742032 & -0.851811 & -0.518567 \\ -0.488358 & -0.48442 & 0.72584 \end{bmatrix}
$$

for proof the result of :
$$
O DO^{T}
$$
is exactly as the **A** matrix.

but the result of:
$$
\sqrt{D} {O}^T = \begin{bmatrix} -1.08827 & 0.0928747 & -0.611241 \\ 0.171643 & -0.733286 & -0.417016 \\ -0.525558 & -0.603047 & 0.844086 \end{bmatrix}
$$

that is different from **X** matrix!

I would be thankful for any idea that can explain why so is and how to correct the answer.

Comment: You might find [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832384/81360) helpful. You have found one of the many solutions to $X^TX = A$, but there is no reason to suspect that the solution you get will be the same as the $X$ you used to generate $A$. All we can say about the two solutions $X = X_1$ (the matrix you used to generate $A$) and $X = X_2$ (the solution you found) is that there is some orthogonal matrix $U$ for which $X_2 = UX_1$.

Comment: X is a matrix that transfer p0 point to p1.
I made a sphere sample point and transferd all with X. so there 
according to:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550167/how-to-find-a-matrix-that-produced-a-symmetric-matrix
we have 9 equation and 9 unknown variable. so there must be a uniqe answer for a one given sample point ( X.p0 = P1 ). how can I find the uniqe solution?

Comment: for a given sample point how can I find the U matrix?
will be the U matrix uniqe for any other sample point?

Comment: The fact that you have 9 equations on unknowns doesn't guarantee that the solution is unique. $x^2 = 1$ is a system of one equation over one variable that has multiple solutions.

Comment: Suppose that $X = X_2$ is the solution that you find to $X^TX = A$. Here's a way to find an orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $X_3 = UX_2$ (so it automatically satisfies $X_3^TX_3 = A$) and $X_3 p_0 = p_1$: we simply need any orthogonal matrix (of the many possible) such that $U(X_2 p_0) = p_1$.  One possibility is given by the [formula I present here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3388120/81360). Because $X_1^TX_1 = X_2^TX_2$, it must be the case that $\|X_2 p_0\| = \|X_1 p_0\| = \|p_1\|$.

Comment: my mean of uniqe is all possible matrices(X). sorry for Verbal mistake.
if X1...Xn be the possible answers and X1 be the our desired answer that we are looking for, then based on a set of 9 polynomial equations and 9 unknowns:
1- I think n must be limited. am I right? if yes how many answer there is?
2- if only X1 is the desired answer, then only X1.p0 = p1 . in other words X2.p0 ≠ p1 ... Xn.p0 ≠ p1. as I mentioned in the first question.
3- based on your answer ther are matrices so that: X1 = U2.X2 = U3.X3 = .... = Un.Xn  . can Householder transformation decompose U2...Un?

Comment: forasmuch as $$ {X}_{1}^{T}{X}_{1}={X}_{n}^{T}{X}_{n} $$
then:
$$
{X}_{1}^{T}{X}_{1}=({U}_{n}{X}_{n})^{T} {U}_{n}{X}_{n}
$$

that gives:
$$
{X}_{1}^{T}{X}_{1}={X}_{n}^{T}{U}_{n}^{T}{U}_{n}{X}_{n}
$$
And this is true when:
 $${U}_{n}^{T}{U}_{n} = I$$
it means:
$${U}_{n}$$ must be an Orthogonal matrix.

does Household transform produce such a matrix?

Comment: next question is that, is such a matrix (U) unique?
if not, for a Un what is the maximum for n?
thank you in advance